# Is there a way to construct a nontrivial semi-direct product of $S_n$ and $D_n$?

Tags: group-theory

I cannot find a way to define the mapping from one group to $\operatorname{Aut}(S_n)$ or $\operatorname{Aut}(D_n)$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, $D_n\le S_n \le Aut(S_n)$ for $n\ge 3$ so it's straightforward.  The first inclusion is because $D_n$ acts faithfully on the n vertices of an n-gon, and the second is because $S_n$ acts faithfully on itself by inner automorphisms.

In fact the second embedding is an isomorphism unless $n=6$, but that's not needed for your problem.